# OpenSSL Does not Create Subject Alternative Name (SAN)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, subject-alternative-names

I have been trying to create a self-signed certificate with subject alternative name; however, although the cretifcate was created successfully, SAN was not added to its details.

Here's the command I used to create singing request.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout server.key -out server.csr -config openssl-san.cnf
```

And here's the content of the configuration file.

```
[ req ]
default_bits           = 2048
distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions         = req_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName    = State or Province Name (full name)
localityName           = Locality Name (eg, city)
organizationName       = Organization Name (eg, company)
commonName             = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default           = **
stateOrProvinceName_default   = ****
localityName_default           = ****
0.organizationName_default     = ******
organizationalUnitName_default = **
emailAddress_default           = *********

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.0   = localhost
```

Certificate details
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Please note that I'm a software developer so creating certificates are not my typical thing

Comment: You only show how you create the CSR - which has the SAN inside. You don't show how you create the certificate, only complain that the certificate (which was created in an undocumented way) does not have the SAN inside. This means you likely don't include the SAN in the certificate - but nothing is known here. Note that SAN are not guaranteed to be copied from the CSR when creating a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal config (`minimal.cnf`) which will give you a self-signed is:

```
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = req_dn
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[ req_dn ]
commonName         = Example Web Service

[ x509_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
# You may need the next line to stop Firefox complaining:
basicConstraints = critical; CA:TRUE
 
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

Create the self-signed certificate with:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -days 720 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.cer -config minimal.cnf
```